# Change telegram bot name on the fly

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

I have a telegram bot that messages on a group. I want the telegram bot to change its “name” from time to time - just like a user can. Is this possible? This means that when I see a message from the bot it can say “ABCbot”, but later it can say “DEFbot”. Let me know!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry but you can't change your telegram via *bot* but you can change it via **@BotFather** as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Go to [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather) and send this command

```
/mybots
```

Then it will show list of your bots. Click on the bot you want change it's name and then click on **Edit Name**

Comment: Yes, I was hoping there would be an api-based way to do it. Strange that a bot can’t change its own name.

Comment: @CarlosF You gotta need to write a bot for that :)

Comment: @j4hangir. If the API allowed it, you could, but it doesn't, so you can't.....

Comment: @boatcoder https://stackoverflow.com/a/72594264/6387880

Comment: I don't understand how `you can't` has been accepted as an answer. It obviously can be done on-the-fly as I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72594264/6387880)

Comment: It's simple. because he asked about Telegram Bot API not Telegram Client API. I wonder how you couldn't understand difference between these two concept. `Pure Python 3 MTProto API Telegram client library, for bots too! `

Answer (score -1):

Use [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) to do that:

```py
await tc.send_message('@botfather', '/setname')
await tc.send_message('@botfather', bot)
await tc.send_message('@botfather', name)
```

`tc` is the instance of `TelegramClient` class.